# Sign-in and Sign-out functions not working [Mhartl's Rails tutorial]

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The title pretty much sums it up - the signin/signout functions don't seem to be working and I've followed the tutorial to a t, needless to say it's quite strange.

*To elaborate on what I mean by "not working" - when I click sign-in and enter my login credentials it simply re-directs me to the /users/id page albeit the nav stays the same as it still has the sign-in option. Similarly, when I was actually signed-in initially (which I can't anymore) the sign-out function just wouldn't do anything and I would remain signed in.*

**_header partial:**

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <%= link_to "sample app", root_path, id: "logo" %>
      <nav>
        <ul class="nav pull-right">
          <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Help", help_path %></li>
          <% if signed_in? %>
            <li><%= link_to "Users", users_path %></li>
            <li id="fat-menu" class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                Account <b class="caret"></b>
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Settings", edit_user_path(current_user) %></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li>
                  <%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, method: "delete" %>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          <% else %>
            <li><%= link_to "Sign in", signin_path %></li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

**Sessions_controller:**

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
      @user = User.new

      respond_to do |format|
        format.html # new.html.erb
        format.json { render json: @user }
      end
    end

  def create
     user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email].downcase)
     if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
       sign_in user
       redirect_back_or user
     else
       flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
       render 'new'
     end
   end

    def destroy
      sign_out
      redirect_to root_url
    end
end
```

**Sessions_helper:**

```
module SessionsHelper

  def sign_in(user)
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
    self.current_user = user
  end

  def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  def sign_out
     self.current_user = nil
     cookies.delete(:remember_token)
   end

   def current_user=(user)
      @current_user = user
   end

   def current_user
     @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
   end

   def current_user?(user)
     user == current_user
   end

   def redirect_back_or(default)
     redirect_to(session[:return_to] || default)
     session.delete(:return_to)
   end

   def store_location
     session[:return_to] = request.url
   end
end

  def remember_token
     cookies.signed[:remember_token] || [nil,nil]
  end
```

**Signin form/Sessions#new**

```
<% provide(:title, "Sign in") %>
<h1>Sign in</h1>


<div class="row">
  <div class="span6 offset3">
    <%= form_for(:session, url: sessions_path) do |f| %>

      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.text_field :email %>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password %>

      <%= f.submit "Sign in", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>

    <p>New user? <%= link_to "Sign up now!", signup_path %></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please let me know if I can provide any other controllers/views/models and I will update the post with them accordingly!

Thanks.

Comment: There are *many* Rails tutorials out there. Citing "the tutorial" is not helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the input - to clarify it is Michael Hartl's Rails tutorial.

Comment: What does your sign in form look like? Have you taken a look at the params hash being posted back to the server on sign in? Also, what version of Rails are you using?

Comment: Rails 3.2.13 and I've added the sign in form to the initial post.

Comment: I suspect issues with the user's `remember_token`. Does the record for the user in the database contain a valid `remember_token`?

Comment: I think you're right @Sunxperous e.g running User.first.remember_token in rails console returns => nil when presumably it should be returning the first users, user token. Any idea on how to get this working?

Comment: Assuming you have defined `create_remember_token` and `before_save :create_remember_token` in your User model, [run `User.first.save(validate: false)` in the console.](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out#code-bootstrap_js) (Refer to the 3rd code snippet after Listing 8.25.)

Answer (score 0):

Look at this line in the sessions controller:

```
redirect_back_or user
```

And the corresponding helper method:

```
def redirect_back_or(default)
  redirect_to(session[:return_to] || default)
  session.delete(:return_to)
end
```

Looks like session variable `session[:return_to]` is not being set, as it is returning false (or nil) causing a redirect to `@user`.

You should be calling the `store_location` helper to set this session variable before doing any authentication magic. Either place it at the top of the `create` action, or use a `before_filter`.

---

Note that `store_location` overwrites `session[:return_to]` without checking for an existing value. If a user enters a wrong password and the login page is rendered again, it will store the login page as the "return to" location. A successful authentication will then redirect back to the login page.

To fix this, use conditional assignment:

```
def store_location
  session[:return_to] ||= request.url
end
```

Comment: Thanks @gg_s, although the problem persists :(